# ¿Porque el mismo proyecto no corre en glassfish 3, pero en glassfish 4 si lo hace de forma correcta?

Tags: java, servidor, glassfish

Actualmente tengo un proyecto que esta montado sobre un servidor glassfish 4.1, pero por algunos motivos externos se decidió usar el servidor de glassfish 3, la situacion es que el mismo proyecto sin modificar absolutamente nada funciona solamente en glassfish 4.1.

El error que sale es el siguiente:

> cannot Deploy monitorLiquidaciones
>   deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [monitorLiquidaciones].

El error en codigo seria el siguiente:

```
   2018-02-06T11:10:24.152-0600|Grave: Exception while deploying the app [monitorLiquidaciones]
2018-02-06T11:10:24.158-0600|Grave: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.<init>(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(XML11Configuration.java:1212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:156)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:818)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:631)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: Schema factory class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl does not extend from SchemaDVFactory.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:75)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar$BuiltinSchemaGrammar.<init>(SchemaGrammar.java:278)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar.<clinit>(SchemaGrammar.java:1296)
    ... 50 more

2018-02-06T11:10:25.621-0600|Grave: Exception while deploying the app [monitorLiquidaciones]
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: Schema factory class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl does not extend from SchemaDVFactory.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:75)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar$BuiltinSchemaGrammar.<init>(SchemaGrammar.java:278)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.SchemaGrammar.<clinit>(SchemaGrammar.java:1296)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.<init>(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(XML11Configuration.java:1212)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.java:156)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:818)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:332)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:306)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:631)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:373)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:94)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:827)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:769)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Nota: Es el mismo proyecto, no se modifico nada asi que no creo que tenga que ver con el codigo del mismo.

Ya hice esta parte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hice el pool connection

```
<jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="" datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" description="" name="GBO">
  <property name="User" value="xxxxxxxxx"></property>
  <property name="Password" value="xxxxxxxxxxx"></property>
  <property name="DataSourceName" value="OracleDataSource"></property>
  <property name="ExplicitCachingEnabled" value="false"></property>
  <property name="MaxStatements" value="0"></property>
  <property name="NetworkProtocol" value="tcp"></property>
  <property name="ImplicitCachingEnabled" value="false"></property>
  <property name="URL" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></property>
  <property name="PortNumber" value="0"></property>
  <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
        <jdbc-resource pool-name="xxx" description="" jndi-name="xxxxxxxxxx"></jdbc-resource>
```

Comment: Conque version de JDK y JEE esta compilado el proyecto???

Comment: @isaac es la version 1.8 para ambos

Answer (score 1):

La clase que te da problemas es `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl`

Seguramente esa clase sea una implementación propia incluída en el servidor (que el `package` empiece por com.sun y luego siga con org.apache me hace sospechar) y no está usando la clase `org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl` que tu aplicación espera.

Tendrás que solucionar el conflicto excluyendo xerces en tu pom.xml o evitando que Glassfish cargue su versión.

Excluir una dependencia en Maven es algo así:

- Ejecuta `mvn dependency:tree` y ve cuáles de tus dependencias dependen a su vez de xerces.
- En esas dependencias directas añade la exclusión,
  algo como lo siguiente.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.openid4java</groupId>
  <artifactId>openid4java</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Hay una entrada en SOen para este tema, pues es algo que pasa a menudo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677572/dealing-with-xerces-hell-in-java-maven

Aquí tienes un enlace a una [página que explica en español cómo funciona](http://antuansoft.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/maven-eliminar-las-dependencias.html) y a la [documentación oficial de maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

Comment: como se excluyen los xerces en un proyecto de java, si leí el articulo de SO, pero no encuentro los fichero a modificar.